# What's are the benefits and cons writing Solana program using Anchor Vs Native

Tags: anchor

I see for the moment two way to write solana program the first one using the solana_program crate only following the structure dictate on the solana doc and the second using anchor, Im wondering what are the benefits writing solana program using only the solana_program crate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of opinion, but the main difference is that Anchor is a framework.  A framework will do a lot of things for you, but not let you do everything as a result.  Here are a few random pros for each:

Anchor:

- defines an IDL consumable by any client
- adds safety checks for free
- reduces boilerplate

Non-anchor:

- use any serialization format
- not restricted by any account checks
- reduce compute usage by doing anything you need, e.g. selectively serializing back into accounts